# executing a load of reads on cassandra getting BusyPoolException

Tags: phantom-dsl

I am trying to execute a high load of queries using [Phantom](https://github.com/outworkers/phantom) version 2.14.1 e.g :

```
case class Foo(id: String, x: Long, y: Long)
val list: List[Foo] = _
list.size = 100000
def find(id: String, x: Long, y:Long )
    select
      .where(_.id eqs id)
      .and(_.ts >= x)
      .and(_.ts < y)
      .fetch()
  }

list.map(f => find(f.id, f.x, f.y)
```

I am getting this exception :

```
[pool-2-thread-91] ERROR com.outworkers.phantom - Failed to execute query SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id = 'some_uuid' AND x >= 1503501104 AND y < 1503501224;
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.BusyPoolException: [localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] Pool is busy (no available connection and the queue has reached its max size 256)))
    at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.reportNoMoreHosts(RequestHandler.java:220)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.access$1200(RequestHandler.java:50)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler$SpeculativeExecution.findNextHostAndQuery(RequestHandler.java:291)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler$SpeculativeExecution$1.onFailure(RequestHandler.java:358)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$6.run(Futures.java:1764)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutor.execute(MoreExecutors.java:456)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$ImmediateFuture.addListener(Futures.java:153)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures.addCallback(Futures.java:1776)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures.addCallback(Futures.java:1713)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler$SpeculativeExecution.query(RequestHandler.java:313)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler$SpeculativeExecution.findNextHostAndQuery(RequestHandler.java:283)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.startNewExecution(RequestHandler.java:118)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.sendRequest(RequestHandler.java:98)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager.executeAsync(SessionManager.java:132)
    at com.outworkers.phantom.ScalaGuavaAdapter$.statementToPromise(ScalaGuavaAdapter.scala:70)
    at com.outworkers.phantom.ScalaGuavaAdapter$.statementToFuture(ScalaGuavaAdapter.scala:32)
    at com.outworkers.phantom.ScalaGuavaAdapter$.fromGuava(ScalaGuavaAdapter.scala:90)
    at com.outworkers.phantom.ScalaGuavaAdapter$.fromGuava(ScalaGuavaAdapter.scala:26)
    at com.outworkers.phantom.builder.query.execution.GuavaAdapter$class.fromGuava(ExecutableStatements.scala:44)
    at com.outworkers.phantom.ScalaGuavaAdapter$.fromGuava(ScalaGuavaAdapter.scala:26)
    at com.outworkers.phantom.builder.query.execution.QueryInterface.future(QueryInterface.scala:71)
    at com.outworkers.phantom.builder.query.execution.ResultQueryInterface.fetch(ResultQueryInterface.scala:131)
```

I tried to configure contact points as suggested but seems that any number that I put in the configuration have zero impact

```
val connector = ContactPoint.LOCAL.withClusterBuilder( ).withoutJMXReporting().withoutMetrics().withPoolingOptions(
      new PoolingOptions()
        .setMaxConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance.LOCAL, 1)
        .setMaxConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance.REMOTE, 2)
        .setMaxRequestsPerConnection(HostDistance.LOCAL,100)
        .setMaxRequestsPerConnection(HostDistance.REMOTE,200)
    )
  ).keySpace(KeySpaceSerializer(keyspace).ifNotExists().`with`(replication eqs SimpleStrategy.replication_factor(1))
    .and(durable_writes eqs true))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think what you are seeing here is related to streaming per se, the problem is the high volume of requests is monopolising the internal thread pool of the Datastax Java Driver, so basically the driver is running out of concurrent connections to Cassandra.

This is to a degree tunable.

```
PoolingOptions.setMaxRequestsPerConnection(HostDistance, int): maximum number of requests per connection;

PoolingOptions.setMaxConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance, int): maximum number of connections in the pool;

PoolingOptions.setMaxQueueSize(int): maximum number of enqueued requests before this exception is thrown.
```

You would set them via the `ClusterBuilder` like this.

```
  val connector = ContactPoint.local
    .noHeartbeat()
    .withClusterBuilder(_.withoutJMXReporting()
      .withoutMetrics().withPoolingOptions(
        new PoolingOptions()
          .setMaxConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance.LOCAL, 15))
          .setMaxRequestsPerConnection(100)
    ).keySpace(KeySpaceSerializer(space).ifNotExists()
      .`with`(replication eqs SimpleStrategy.replication_factor(1))
      .and(durable_writes eqs true)
    )
```

I haven't actually checked whether the values are correct all, merely showing you the DSL configuration.

Comment: Thank you very much. but it seems that this configuration had absolutely no impact. I tried to do it in a simple loop with a lot of reads (i.e without akka-stream or kafka) and still got the same results. I am using version 2.12.1.  is it a version issue ?

Comment: @igx you can try the latest which is 2.14.1, some things have changed, but the error you get is from the underlying Datastax Driver which I think has not changed.

Can you make sure the values you have set are actually higher than the defaults it would use had you not specified the values? You could have made them even lower without meaning to.

Comment: thank you very much. I did all that you suggested (see above) but it seems that it had no effect.  I have updated my question accordingly

Comment: @igx I'd try and go for either Play Iteratees, or at least use paginates queries with `iterateRecord` and query pagination. If you read the docs on `fetch` it will tell you it's only suitable for small ops, as it will greedy fetch all the results in the DB as well as greedy map them to your Scala record type.

Comment: I think that pagination will not be much help since the number of records returned is not too big but it is the number of queries.  I tried to search the docs regarding the `fetch` as suggested here https://github.com/outworkers/phantom/wiki/Querying but couldn't see that it is says that it is suitable for small ops. can you please reference me to the right doc? also the operation is relatively small and shouldn't return large result set.